# Can bacteria or virus travel on an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, biophysics

I was wondering if it is possible for bacteria or viruses to travel through space on an electromagnetic wave?

Comment: there are optical tweezers, using lasers, used to manipulate bacterias and viruses.

Comment: Nothing with mass can travel at $c$, so a bacteria or virus cannot travel through space with an individual photon.

Answer (score 3):

Light bodies like bacteria and viruses are pushed out of the solar system by radiation pressure if they are notvdedinyegratef by solar radiation. So yes, they can be transported by light but not to us as long as the sun shines.

Radiation pressure falls off as $r^{-2}$ just like gravitational acceleration. For a sperical object of biological density smaller than 9 micron radiation pressure wins.

Comment: Do you have a source for this or is just your opinion? They really are or they could be?

Comment: You can find my opinions on twitter :-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you look at a powerful laser you can see dust being pushed by the laser, so they can be strong enough to move bacteria or viruses.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08678). This is a form of optical tweezer, and beads attached to molecules in living systems are moved and the force on polypeptides by various actions, actin myosin motors etc, have been measured. So it is possible that bacteria or viruses migrate between stars by electromagnetic pressure.

Comment: I didn't d/v (and I really wish comments on them were required) but the reason I comment (FWIW)  is the link above is dead on my pc. The moving through space idea would seem possible based on the lifespan of discovered and thawed frozen bacteria, but maybe I am just repeating what the paper you cite says.  The link has an extra %20https at the start, I think that's the problem.

Comment: link is not working , it is wrong  http://www.%20https.com//arxiv.org/abs/1609.08678  . there is this  https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08678 but it is not about bacteria.

Comment: There are no optical tweezers in space.